# Error in Deserializing customized Stanford ner model

Tags: stanford-nlp

I had created my own NER model. While using that I got the following exception:

```
Error deserializing ../classifiers/ner-model.ser.gz.
Error snipet is:

Loading classifier from .../classifiers/ner-model.ser.gz ... Error deserializing /home/hrudya/Music/WORKSPACE_SAP/NER/classifiers/ner-model.ser.gz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.FeatureFactory
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1752)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1703)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1686)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(CRFClassifier.java:2825)
    at accs.sap.NER.Test.<clinit>(Test.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.FeatureFactory
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.loadClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2606)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1622)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1738)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1749)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is more of a statement than a question. Can you add more detail ? Please refer the help center for instructions on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I got the result. It is mainly due to version issue. Stanford NER works fine for the version 3.5.2.